# PHP - Unexpected Behavior in Nested foreach Loop

Tags: php

**Some Background**

I have 2 arrays with the following information:

```
$x = [
    ['name' => 'Fred', 'ykey' => 'A', 'rank' => '1', 'VIP' => '1'],
    ['name' => 'Fred', 'ykey' => 'B', 'rank' => '2', 'VIP' => '1'],
    ['name' => 'Joe', 'ykey' => 'A', 'rank' => '1', 'VIP' => '1'],
    ['name' => 'Joe', 'ykey' => 'B', 'rank' => '2', 'VIP' => '1'],
    ['name' => 'Frank', 'ykey' => 'A', 'rank' => '1', 'VIP' => '0'],
    ['name' => 'Frank', 'ykey' => 'B', 'rank' => '2', 'VIP' => '0']
]
```

and

```
$y = [
    'A' => [
        'hasVIPmember' => false,
        'slots' = [] //X elements will be placed here
    ]
    'B' => [
        'hasVIPmember' => false,
        'slots' = [] //X elements will be placed here
    ]
```

The goal is to place each of the elements in `$x` into `$y` with only one VIP member. I have a method to place the VIP members and then one to place everyone else. The information in `$x` is obtained from a database. The '1' in `VIP` means `true`.

**The Problem**

The problem I am having is outlined in the comments in the code below.

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++){
    foreach($x as $z){
        //all Xs are seen here (after all iterations complete)
        if($z['VIP'] == 1 && $z['rank'] == $i){
            //Only Fred and Joe elements of X are shown here. (after all iterations complete)
            if(!($y[$z['ykey']]['hasVIPmember'])){
                //Only 'Fred' elements are shown here. Why?(after all iterations complete)
                $y[$z['ykey']]['slots'][]= $z;
                $y[$z['ykey']]['hasVIPmember'] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem is, as you can see from the comments, when I perform `if(!($y[$z['ykey']]['hasVIPmember'])){...}` I only see the elements with the name "Fred" and, consequently, Fred is placed in both A and B.

**The Question**

Why is the list of items that are iterated through narrowed further in the final if statement? Is there any way to correct this behavior?

Comment: well, you never change `hasVIPmember` inside the loop, so even after you add a vipmember, you'll just keep adding more vip members,b ecause you never reset the flag to say one was added previously.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for pointing that out. I actually do have that in my original code. I just missed it when I moved it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run the iteration Fred is first for both ranks 1 and 2. As it runs, it adds Fred to $y and then skips over the rest because at that point $y[hasVIPmember] is true. You would need to find a way to invalidate Fred from the running after he is added to any $y by using some kind of counter or key, or change your data set.

```
$used = NULL;
for($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++){
    foreach($x as $z){
        //all Xs are seen here (after all iterations complete)
        if($z['VIP'] == 1 && $z['rank'] == $i){
            //Only Fred and Joe elements of X are shown here. (after all iterations complete)
            if(!($y[$z['ykey']]['hasVIPmember'])){
                // looks for used
                if (!($z['name'] == $used)) {
                    $y[$z['ykey']]['slots'][]= $z;
                    $y[$z['ykey']]['hasVIPmember'] = true;
                    $used = $z['name']; //add Fred to the used name list
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! `if( ... $z['rank'] == $i){...}` prevents that from happening. I am seeing the following at the second comment (after the first if statement): When `$i = 1` I see the first entry for Fred and then the first entry for Joe. When `$i = 2` I see the second entry for Fred and then the second entry for Joe.

Comment: After rereading your answer, I found that you were correct. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Reason for the unexpected behavior is that you are using

```
$y[$z['ykey']]['hasVIPmember'] = true;
```

This lead to set hasVIPmember = true for all names in $x that has ykey='A' in the first iteration.Therefore after fred has been entered joe is skipped.

Similarly it sets  hasVIPmember = true for all names in $x that has ykey='B' in the second iteration.

Even if you had more names in $x they all would have been excluded.

This code gives the desirable output ,

```
<?php

$x = [
['name' => 'Fred', 'ykey' => 'A', 'rank' => '1', 'VIP' => '1'],
['name' => 'Joe', 'ykey' => 'A', 'rank' => '1', 'VIP' => '1'],
['name' => 'Fred', 'ykey' => 'B', 'rank' => '2', 'VIP' => '1'],
['name' => 'Joe', 'ykey' => 'B', 'rank' => '2', 'VIP' => '1'],
['name' => 'Frank', 'ykey' => 'A', 'rank' => '1', 'VIP' => '0'],
['name' => 'Frank', 'ykey' => 'B', 'rank' => '2', 'VIP' => '0']
];

$y = [
'A' => [ 'hasVIPmember' => false , 'slots' => []  ],
'B' => [ 'hasVIPmember' => false , 'slots' => []  ]

 ];


for($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++){
foreach($x as $z){
    //all Xs are seen here (after all iterations complete)
    if($z['VIP'] == 1 && $z['rank'] == $i){
       //Only Fred and Joe elements of X are shown here. (after all iterations complete)
        if(!($y[$z['ykey']]['hasVIPmember']))
          {
          echo $z['name']; // printing to check the name 
          echo $z['ykey']; // printing to check the ykey
          echo "<br>";  
          $y[$z['ykey']]['slots'][]= $z;

    }

}

}
}

?>
```

[image]

Comment: I need to have only 1 VIP member in A and 1 VIP member in B. That is why I have that flag there, otherwise I will get multiples in each.

Comment: That's correct. I failed to say that order was important in my question. Sorry about that.